# In Java 7, how to crete a real life example to demonstrate the difference between Files.exists and Files.notExists?

Tags: java, io, java-7, file-permissions

From the documentation of [Files.notExists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29):

> This method is intended for cases where it is required to take action when it can be confirmed that a file does not exist..........Note that this method is not the complement of the exists method. Where it is not possible to determine if a file exists or not then both methods return false.

The theoretical difference is understood. It can be that `File.exists()` returns `false`, but that does not necessarily mean that the file does not exists. Java 7 provides us with the `Files.notExists()` method to deal with this kind of situation.

I've tried creating a file on Windows 7, and denying all permissions to it (including Admin). But this did not produce the behavior of `File.exists()` returning `false`. Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will work. In your case your were getting denying permissions issue you may check the folder in operating system installation partition. (C:\). Following will work.

```
   Path path = Paths.get("D:\\TestFolder");
    if (Files.exists(path)) {
        System.out.println("exist");
    }
    if (Files.notExists(path)) {
        System.out.println("not exist");
    }
```

`javadoc` says about `Files.notExists()`

> Tests whether the file located by this path does not exist. This
>   method is intended for cases where it is required to take action when
>   it can be confirmed that a file does not exist. Note that this method
>   is not the  complement of the exists method. Where it is not possible
>   to determine if a  file exists or not then both methods return false.
>   As with the exists method,  the result of this method is immediately
>   outdated. If this method indicates  the file does exist then there is
>   no guarantee that a subsequence attempt to create the file will
>   succeed. Care should be taken when using this method in security
>   sensitive applications.

Comment: indeed this worked. Can you please explain why Files.notExists on this path returned false? (my D drive is a CD-ROM with nothing in it).

Comment: @Vitaliy please use other drive

Comment: I think the key is that you have nothing in your CD drive.  My Windows 8 machine is a VM with the D drive mapped to the boot desk and Java can tell that D:\\TestFolder does in fact not exist.  Without the CD in the drive, I guess it is ambiguous.